# Use date to manage subscriptions. Android. Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, date

My problem is with this activity. I want to get the time, compare it to the time on the database, and then if the subscription hasnt expired show a button, if it has hide it. Plus i want to show the credits a user has, and image and his name on top. I have tried many things, but it keeps crashing for some reason.

```
public void getthedate(){

   calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final SimpleDateFormat mdformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy / MM / dd ");
   // strDate = "Current Date : " + mdformat.format(calendar.getTime());

 //  futurecal = Calendar.getInstance();
  //  futurecal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
  //  futuredate = mdformat.format(futurecal.getTime());

    DatabaseReference subtime = mDatabase.child("users").child(univ).child(uid);
    subtime.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          subtimedate = dataSnapshot.child("subdate").getValue().toString();
            String username = dataSnapshot.child("Full name").getValue().toString();
            String coinstring = dataSnapshot.child("coins").getValue().toString();
            coinview.setText(coinstring);
            String imglink = dataSnapshot.child("imageuri").getValue().toString();
            Glide.with(c).load(imglink).into(userthing);
            hellostring.setText("Hey" + username + "!");
            Date subdatecal = null;
            try {
                subdatecal = mdformat.parse(subtimedate);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar newestcal = Calendar.getInstance();
          newestcal.setTime(subdatecal);

            if (newestcal.after(mdformat.format(calendar.getTime()))){
                substat.setText("Active");
                substat.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
               //do something if subscription hasnt expired
            }else{
                gotonotes.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                substat.setText("Expired");
                substat.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    /*
    DatabaseReference subtime = mDatabase.child("users").child(univ).child(uid).child("subdate");
    subtime.setValue(futuredate);

    set new subscription

    */
/* if (calendar.after(futurecal)){
     use this to check if date has passed
 }*/
}
```

In the oncreate i have setup everything.

```
substat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.substat);
hellostring = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hellostring);
coinview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coinview);
userthing = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userimagething);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        friendbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.friendsbtn);

        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

this is logcat from my phone on android studio when the activity crashes

```
10-22 19:00:46.363 20227-20227/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-22 19:00:46.473 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.studybuddy.mixal.android-2/lib/arm64
10-22 19:00:46.592 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
10-22 19:00:46.635 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-22 19:00:46.639 20227-20261/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
    To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.studybuddy.mixal.android
10-22 19:00:46.703 20227-20261/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
10-22 19:00:46.705 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
10-22 19:00:46.718 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
10-22 19:00:46.899 20227-20284/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
10-22 19:00:46.949 20227-20284/com.studybuddy.mixal.android W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000086/n/arm64-v8a
10-22 19:00:46.960 20227-20272/com.studybuddy.mixal.android E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
10-22 19:00:46.961 20227-20272/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-22 19:00:46.971 20227-20272/com.studybuddy.mixal.android W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so
    dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found
    Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
10-22 19:00:46.971 20227-20272/com.studybuddy.mixal.android E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
10-22 19:00:47.058 20227-20299/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
10-22 19:00:48.781 20227-20227/com.studybuddy.mixal.android I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 20227 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Add the crash log

Comment: Thats a problem, i dont run the app on emulators, i run it on my phone, thus i cant get a crash log.

Comment: @MikeKioulMikeKioulepoglou Phones have the same crash log.  Attach it to your pc and run adb logcat

Comment: Also, not the best way of doing things.  All someone has to do to unexpire themselves is set their clock backwards in settings.  If you want semi-accurate time for something like this, you can't rely on the client.

Comment: Thanks, i added the logcat from the moment the activity crashes. For now security isnt a big issue. Ill probably have to set cloud functions for firebase to check dates on the server and not the client. But for now this approach is fine for me.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. We need to take a look at the error not at those warnings. Please also indicate the line at which the error occurs.